# how to convert map keys to uppercase in using java 8 streams?

Tags: hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I have a method as below

```
private Map<String,List<String>>  createTableColumnListMap(List<Map<String,String>> nqColumnMapList){

        Map<String, List<String>> targetTableColumnListMap = 
                nqColumnMapList.stream()
                     .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                     .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
        return targetTableColumnListMap;
    }
```

I want to uppercase the map keys but couldn't find a way to do it. is there a java 8 way to achieve this?

Comment: Replace `Map.Entry::getKey` with `e -> e.getKey().toUppercase()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer for your question [which you can copy and paste] :**

```
Map<String, List<String>> targetTableColumnListMap = nqColumnMapList.stream().flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().toUpperCase(), Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: It will be better if when you down-vote you should better give some explanation. Just silently down-voting won't make you more intelligent , You are still not intelligent because you down-voted without watching what I wanted to convey.

Comment: pls provide the reason to downvote because it worked for me.

Comment: My gut says the answer provided by @svarog would be faster.

Answer (score 16):

This doesn't require any fancy manipulation of Collectors. Lets say you have this map

```
Map<String, Integer> imap = new HashMap<>();
imap.put("One", 1);
imap.put("Two", 2);
```

Just get a stream for the `keySet()` and collect into a new map where the keys you insert are uppercased:

```
Map<String, Integer> newMap = imap.keySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.toUpperCase(), key -> imap.get(key)));

// ONE - 1
// TWO - 2
```

**Edit:**

@Holger's comment is correct, it would be better (and cleaner) to just use an entry set, so here is the updated solution

```
Map<String, Integer> newMap = imap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey().toUpperCase(), entry -> entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Redefining the task, changing both, input and output, to come to the conclusion that it can be implemented simpler than the OP’s actual task, is not a real solution. Besides that, streaming over the `keySet` might look simpler, but performing a lookup for *every* key is a waste of resources, compared to streaming over the `entrySet()` in the first place, which provides the mapped value for free.